# Use request.getRequestDispatcher(myurl).forward(request,response) but not working

Tags: servlets

When I use  `request.getRequestDispatcher(myurl).forward(request, response)` in servlet to jump to another HTML page, I find it doesn't work. A response can be seen in web browser but the page just doesn't change.

[image: what webbrowser displayed]

I tried `response.sendRedirect(myurl)` then, and it also doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public class ServletDemo extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("get");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect("/ForwardTest/new.html");
//      request.getRequestDispatcher("/new.html").forward(request, response);
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

Each time I run this, just get a "success" output in console. That means `getRequestDispatcher` had run, but not correctly.

Comment: That mostly looks correct and it should work.  Except I'd remove `setContentType()` and `setCharacterEncoding()` from the doPost(), they aren't doing anything.  What is in the file /ForwardTest/new.html?  If it looks like the picture you linked to, then it is working.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and I've edited those mentioned. The file 'new.html' is what the picture showing. However, the web browser always stays the original page and doesn't change, even if getting the response.

Comment: I misunderstood the problem.  You originally only described what happened, not what you were trying to do.  What's in the server access log?  You should see a line with a 302 status code and a 200 status code.

Comment: Yes, the status of "ServletDemo" is 302 and the status of "new.html" is 200.